# Mathf.Clamp inside of a sphere radius Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple joystick move script. I restricted its movement on x and z axis with a Mathf.Clamp. What I am trying to achive is to use that function inside a sphere radius.

I need the gameobject movement restrict its movement if the gameobjects position is outside of the radius.

```
   void UpdateMoveJoystick()
    {
        horizontale = moveJoystick.Horizontal;
        float ver = moveJoystick.Vertical;
        Vector2 convertedXY = ConvertWithCamera(Camera.main.transform.position, horizontale, ver);
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(convertedXY.x, 0, convertedXY.y).normalized;
        transform.Translate(direction * 0.02f * speed, Space.World);
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

       RestrictMovement();
    }

     void RestrictMovement()
    {
        var position1 = transformPos.transform.position.x;
        var position2 = transformPos.transform.position.x;
        var position3 = transformPos.transform.position.z;
        var position4 = transformPos.transform.position.z;
        float xMovementClamp = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, position1 += leftBoundry, position2 += rightBoundry);        
        float zMovementClamp = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, position3 += DownBoundry, position4 += UpBoundry);
        transform.position = new Vector3(xMovementClamp, transform.position.y, zMovementClamp);
    }
```

Anyway Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`Vector2.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html). This method takes a `Vector2` and allows you to ensure that the `magnitude` (or vector length) is no longer than the desired length (or the radius of the circle).

With this in mind, the `RestrictMovement` method from your code would look something like this:

```cs
public float boundryRadius = 20.0f;

void RestrictMovement()
{
    var positionXY = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);

    positionXY = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(positionXY, boundryRadius);

    transform.position = new Vector3(positionXY.x, positionXY.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

This would clamp the `GameObject` in the `boundryRadius` specified around the world position of `0, 0, 0`. Additional maths can be used to change the centre of the circular boundary.

Comment: But how to calculate the centre of the circular boundary I tried Vector3.Distance from my center point but that didn't worked.:(